# How to dynamically load the Google Places API Javascript Library with varying API keys into an Ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-places-api, google-places

I am developing an app using the Ionic Framework (Ionic 3) where my users that are associated with different organisations can enter data (the relevant data in this case is a city name) and I use the Google Places API to retrieve photos of these cities.

Until a few months ago I was using the API calls outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) without issue.

However, now the requests no longer return photos and I am receiving errors related to CORB (Cross Origin Resource Blocking) and I am no longer able to use the API calls within my app.

According to the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), I am required to load the Google Maps javascript library within my HTML.

> Loading the library
>   The Places service is a self-contained library, separate from the main Maps JavaScript API code. To use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap URL:
>
> `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

I am not completely how to sure how to do this in ionic/angular.

I think I could just insert this on the index.html page, however my issue is that the API key in the link needs to be changed dynamically. A different Google Places API key will be used depending on which organisation the user belongs to. How am I able to dynamically use this library within ionic and dynamically change the API key? It is possible that the used key will need to be changed during the same login session (in the case that a user belongs to multiple organisations and is logging different data as a part of each organisation)